# How can I get a single result object in jq?

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON file like this:

```
{
    "cases": [
        {"id": "1", "count": 2, "ignore": "f"},
        {"id": "2", "count": 7, "ignore": "o"},
        {"id": "3", "count": 11, "ignore": "o"}
    ]
}
```

Doing `jq '.cases[] | { "\(.id)" : .count }' test.json` gives

```
{
  "1": 2
}
{
  "2": 7
}
{
  "3": 11
}
```

but I need

```
{ 
  "1": 2, 
  "2": 7, 
  "3": 11 
}
```

How can I get there?

Answer (score 3):

You need to collect the results into an array and `add` them

```
.cases | map({ "\(.id)" : .count }) | add
```

Comment: Ohh, leaving out the `[]` after `cases` is the important ingredient!

Answer (score 2):

[`from_entries`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries) sounds like the obvious choice. First map your input array to an array of key-value pairs, then construct an object from this array:

```
.cases | map({ key: .id, value: .count }) | from_entries
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach using `reduce` which iteratively builds up the result object:

```bash
reduce .cases[] as {$id, $count} ({}; .[$id] = $count)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/409flyFmUL-)